# Can't go in layers when in pattern editing mode in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, patterns

I am wanting to fill this path with a different colour. I have made it into a repeat pattern so I am in tile mode. It didn't allow me for some reason to live paint bucket fill the shape. I tried to double click to go into the layer and it doesn't seem that this is possible in the tile editing mode in the pattern tool?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** use the live paint bucket on patterns. That's what the warning is telling you.

Simply select objects and change their color. Don't use the Live Paint Bucket because live paint groups can not be created inside pattern editing mode.